# How to connect mysql database in openshift from workbench?

Tags: mysql, openshift, mysql-workbench

I want to remotely connect mysql database deployed in openshift from mysql-workbench.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the `rhc port-forward` command.
Try checking out the port-forwarding section of the developer portal for more information: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-forwarding.html